# как подключить Ethereum Wallet к приватному блокчейну

Tags: javascript, linux

Есть приватный блокчейн. Необходимо подключить Wallet к нему.

https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/09/16/ethereum-wallet-developer-preview

Команда `$ geth --networkdid "1234" --datadir "/some/other/path" --ipcpath "/home/<username>/.ethereum/geth.ipc"` не дает результата, запускается только консольная версия.